# How to programmatically read the current Filter Table on a WCF Router

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-routing, wcf-behaviour

We have an existing wcf router with the following configuration:

```
    <routing>
        <filters>
            <filter name="Other" filterType="MatchAll" />
            <filter name="action1" filterType="Action" filterData="http://tempuri.org/action2" />
            <filter name="action2" filterType="Action" filterData="http://tempuri.org/action1" />
        </filters>
        <filterTables>
            <filterTable name="FilterTable">
                <add filterName="action1" endpointName="Service1" priority="1" />
                <add filterName="action2" endpointName="Service2" priority="1" />
                <add filterName="Other" endpointName="Service1" priority="0" />
            </filterTable>
        </filterTables>
    </routing>
```

We would like to be able to query the router to ask "given a request, which endpoint will you route to?"

Is there a way to programmatically execute the routing through an API?  e.g. run a request through a routing method which will return the endpoint name